# How to stop music on Xamarin forms app when leaving an app and play it when back

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms  would like to know how to stop/pause music when leave the app. and Play the music when  I back on the app

I use a function in my ConttentPage to read and play a music :

```
ISimpleAudioPlayer AudioPlayerSucces;
void InitMyAudio()
{


    string filenamesuccess = "Lea.MyAudios.Question.success_song.wav";

  
    using (Stream streamSuccess = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filenamesuccess))
    {
        AudioPlayerSucces = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        AudioPlayerSucces.Load(streamSuccess);
    }

     AudioPlayerSucces.Play();
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need the instance of the object to be able to stop/close (AudioPlayerSucces).  Presently it is a local object in a class.  So you would need a method in the class to stop/close instead of play.  If object is stopped than all you need to to play.  If object is closed than you would need to load and play.

Comment: So How to create a method to put AudioPlayerSucces.Stop() when the app is in background and AudioPlayerSucces.Play() when the user come back to app

Comment: Do you see the player in Task Manager.  You can get the process by name.  I would have to do more research to figure out how to connect using the handle.

Comment: use the `OnStart`, `OnSleep` and `OnResume` app lifecycle methods

Comment: @Jason How to use OnStart while my function is not in App.Xalm.cs

Comment: use `MessagingCenter`.  Or expose a public method in your page that can be called from `App`.  Or raise an event in `App` that your page can subscribe to.

Comment: @Jason The best option for me is MessagingCenter because my methode use many other varialbe;  How to use MessagingCenter while my AudioPlayerSucces.Stop()  is in my content page  and the song file is read from my content page

Comment: Subscribe in your page and Send from App